# File not exists when reading file in Android

Tags: android

```
  File file = new File("file:///storage/sdcard0/myfile.txt");
  if (file.exists()) {
     //...
  }
```

I see the file is in my sdcard, but why file.exists() always return false?

Comment: In which device you are testing it ?

Comment: I debug my android project in real device.

Comment: try with `"Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + /myfile.txt"` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly and which that device model ? like Samsung Duos ? Micromax ? etc

Comment: Maybe `/mnt/sdcard` (or `/sdcard`, which I think is a link to the former)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try without `file://`

```
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/myfile.txt");
  if (file.exists()) {
     //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this-

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myfile.txt");
if (file.exists()) {
 //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you tell me why I need to do this conversion and why the path I used not work?

Comment: Becuase Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the root path till your sdcard directory. which is usually "mnt/sdcard/". you can also replace by "mnt/sdcard/myfile.txt" or "/storage/sdcard0/myfile.txt".

Comment: How about when I read file from sdcard1 instead of sdcard0, I think your way may not work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't try because I need to read file from multiple sdcard, your way may not work well in this situation I think.

Comment: sdcard0 is the main sdcard and sdcard1 is external sdcard. so it may not work.